Django GRPC Framework Issues
I am trying to use GRPC frameowrk in Django (latest version). I am facing an error that says:
TypeError: requires_system_checks must be a list or tuple.
After commenting the below code in base.ppy, the error gets resolved.
if (
not isinstance(self.requires_system_checks, (list, tuple))
and self.requires_system_checks != ALL_CHECKS
):
raise TypeError("requires_system_checks must be a list or tuple.")
But is there any other work around for this so that we are not needed to make changes in the environment.

Your question lacks sufficient detail whereby we could help. Please update your question to include the specific process you have followed, your protobuf (or some subset thereof) and what you did to cause the error.
